# Remove the default shadow from the unordered list group in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove the default box-shadow from the unordered list group in bootstrap.There is the default shadow in the list-group special. My html is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-4">
     <ul class="list-group special">
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">About Royal</a></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Message from MD</a></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Director's Profile</a></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Organization Structure</a></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Member Asssociation</a></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">About Nepal</h2></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-8"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I applied the following css:

```
  ul.special{
    box-shadow:none;
    }
```

However, the default box shadow is always there? Plz help how to remove it?I would highly appreciate the help.

Comment: i can't see the box shadow :(  http://jsfiddle.net/jvhp3jav/

Comment: Have you used also prefix for other browser?

Answer (score 0):

There's no `box-shadow` on the `.list-group`, look at the unpacked CSS https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css lines 5100 - 5120. If you want to remove the border then you can do the following in CSS that comes after the Bootstrap CSS.

**CSS **

```
.list-group.special .list-group-item {
   border-width:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think you are talking about the border, not the shadow.**

It is simply to change. You have to add one line to your CSS:

```
ul.special .list-group-item{
border: 0 !important;
}
```